# Use mongoose with populated object and returning a cursor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, cursor

I want to use a cursor with mongoose to avoid the usage of high amount of RAM. The problem is that the object I am requesting from database must be populated before returning the cursor. Is that possible?

Example:

```
function getFilterCursor (user, filter) {
 query = { user: user._id }

 return DataModel
  .find(query)
  .populate("properties.id")
  .lean()
  .cursor()
}
```

The result is the object without populated `properties.id`.

Thanks.

Comment: what is `populate("properties.id")`? you can do a `populate` only if in your model the property is an external reference. Can you post your model?

Comment: `properties` is an array of objects, and `id` is a reference to properties collection.

Comment: ok then you should `populate("properties")` BUT "properties" in your model should be referenced by a schema. Please post your schemas & models